# Script to load image into container when clicked on anchor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This may sound very dumb to many, but my brain is just stumped.

I have 10 links and would like a different image to load into a container each time a link is clicked. That doesn't seem to hard, right?

```
<div class="sidebar_content">
<ul>&nbsp;
        <li><a data-file="CF6-80C0.jpg?v=1">CF6-80C0</a></li>
        <li><a data-file="CF6-80C1.jpg?v=1">CF6-80C1</a></li>
        <li><a data-file="CF6-80C2.jpg?v=1">CF6-80C2</a></li>
        <li><a data-file="CF6-80C3.jpg?v=1">CF6-80C3</a></li>
        <li><a data-file="CF6-80C4.jpg?v=1">CF6-80C4</a></li>
        <li><a data-file="CF6-80C5.jpg?v=1">CF6-80C5</a></li>
        <li><a data-file="CF6-80C6.jpg?v=1">CF6-80C6</a></li>
        <li><a data-file="CF6-80C7.jpg?v=1">CF6-80C7</a></li>
        <li><a data-file="CF6-80C8.jpg?v=1">CF6-80C8</a></li>
        <li><a data-file="CF6-80C9.jpg?v=1">CF6-80C9</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My container in the css is

```
 .bom_container { position: absolute; width: 720px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid #000; }
```

So how do I get these data-files into my container? My JavaScripting skills are beyond new!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/LzZnm/

```
// jQuery syntactic sugar to run after page loads
$(function () {
    // attach a click event to anything with a data-file attribute
    $("[data-file]").on('click', function (evt) {
        // figure out what was clicked
        var clickedEl = $(evt.target);
        // get the data-file attribute
        var dataFile = clickedEl.attr('data-file');
        var container = $(".bom_container");
        // empty the div
        container.empty();
        // create image element
        var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", dataFile)
        // add it to the container
        container.append(img);
        // or update the background image
        // container.css('background-image','url('+ dataFile +')');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, @Phil. I loved the js fiddle example! I'm going to try this one but please tell me where to put this script. Do I place this script in my javascript file? If so where. Or would I put it at the top of the page that has the sidebar_content?

Comment: Actually,I just put the script at the top of my sidebar_content page and it works!!! I'm dancing in my office!!! Now I need to just figure out how to make the images fade in and out so they are just not stark up on the page. I think I can figure out how to manipulate an animate opacity function. Thank you again, @Phil, this got me through the biggest stump I've been in!

Comment: @LisaG. You can put the script anywhere it only runs after the page is loaded. jQuery has [fading](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/) effects that should help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Detect the click, and set either the background image or the html content of the container:

```
$('a[data-file]').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.bom_container').css('background-image','url('+$(this).attr('data-file')+')');
    //or, if you want to load it not as a background:
    $('.bom_container').html('<img src="'+$(this).attr('data-file')+'" />');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li a').on('click', function() {
  var imgSrc = $(this).data('file');
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = imgSrc;

  $('.bom_container').append(img);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Case, if you want insert image as HTML element.

```
$(function () {
    $('ul').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $('div.sidebar_content').children('img').remove();
        $('<img />').attr('src', $(this).data('file')).appendTo('div.sidebar_content');
    });
    });
```

Case, if you want insert image as background:

```
$(function () {
        $('ul').on('click', 'a', function () {
            $('div.sidebar_content').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data('file') + ')');
        });
        });
```